# How to reduce response time of PUT method in express Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node js +express js for back-end development on window environment  and the response time for the simple PUT request is **5-6 sec** and using express version **4.x.x** and node is **6.9.10**.

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/test', function(req, res) {
     res.send("test put api response");
})
var port = 8000;
app.listen(port);
```

Please tell me is there any issue with express version or some other issue.

Comment: This is the code executing or some-other logic is there??

Comment: The code looks relatively simple and is unlikely to be the bottleneck. How are you calling the API? Is the call made from another external system?

Comment: this is only the simple code.

Comment: No I am not making the call form another external system, running it locally.

Comment: @AnitaMehta No it should not be,,, Its very simple code... Did u check whether after hitting the URL it reached the server as quickly as possible?? Or its taking some sec to reach??

Comment: Are you calling the endpoint by using `localhost:port`, `0.0.0.0:port` or are you hitting it with your machine's actual ip address?

Comment: How long does it take to `ping` the same host?  Does a `tracert` to the same host show anything useful?

Comment: @SamuelToh`hitting it with localhost:port

Comment: @Subburaj yes it is taking time to hit on sever. For other request it is working fine, problem is with only put request.

Comment: How are you making the PUT request?  Please show that code.  How large is the body of the PUT?

Comment: @jfriend00`only four to five feilds are there in json,{
  "packageGroupCode": "P02",
    "packageGroupName":"package2",
    "description": "package2",
    "moduleId":"M02",
    "active": false
 }

Comment: Well, if you aren't sending the request properly, then the sender may be waiting for you to finish sending or the receiving server may be waiting for the end of the incoming request.  I suspect the problem is on the sending end.  We need to know how you are sending the request in order to look at that.

Comment: @jfriend00 using postman to make the post request that all and content type json I am selecting

Comment: Please add the exact postman command line you are using to your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you please tell what is the best way to send the request or data

Comment: Postman is fine if done properly.

Comment: This is the header which is sending :Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →34
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 30 May 2017 07:36:39 GMT
ETag →W/"22-hgMYDIBjSHOAdxgW5Fdg2yc6jUU"
Server →nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Via →1.1 hybrid.websense 10c
X-Bst-Info →t=1496129799,h=10c,p=160733_3213:1_2354,c=1,v=7.9.58904.51
X-Bst-Request-Id →4RCZ3h:rMq:253665
X-Powered-By →Express

Comment: try app.put('/test,function(){}) instead of app.use('/test',function())

Comment: @arjunkori how it will come to know that it is PUT request

Comment: @arjunkori in routing i m using put only

Comment: @AnitaMehta the request is actually being reverse-proxied by an NGINX server, running which looks to be security filtering software. The most likely culprit for the slow requests will be that.

Comment: how you are requesting the server ? i executed the same code which is giving me response in 29 ms.

Comment: @arjunkori`form postman I am requesting the servre

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html and in postman select PUT method from dropdown and pass url :http://localhost:8000/test

Comment: @arjunkori which version of node and express you is using

Comment: node v6.9.2 and express 4.13.4